# Having issue with pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I tried to use [this](http://www.onlinetuting.com/pagination-in-php-mysqli/) code for my project by I got these error

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sims/searchuser.php on line 178

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sims/searchuser.php on line 181

Notice:Undefined variable: total_pages’ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sims/searchuser.php on line 194
```

```html
<?php

//Now select all from table

$query = "SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `phone`, `email`* FROM `user_table`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// Count the total records
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

//Going to first page
echo "<center><a href=’searchuser.php?page=1′>”.’First Page’.”</a> ";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

echo "<a href=’searchuser.php?page=”.$i.”‘>”.$i.”</a> ";
};
// Going to last page
echo "<a href=’searchuser.php?page=$total_pages’>”.’Last Page’.”</a></center> ";
?>
```

Undefined variable: `total_pages` in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sims/searchuser.php on line 194

Here is my coding

Comment: How confident are you about the query
    SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `phone`, `email`* FROM `user_table`
?

Comment: `*` <<<<<<<<<<<< get rid of that.

Comment: Show us the searchuser.php. You have a lot of issues in your code: `es’>”.’Last Page’.”</` It's far from solvable.

Comment: oh those too ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: You have an error in your SQL-Query: `email*`

Comment: One should not code with Word. There are (code) editors just for that.